# „ausziehen“ richtig in einem Satz verwenden

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Wenn man einen Immobilienmakler anschreibt:

> Ich habe vor, in einem Monat auszuziehen.

er weißt worum es geht.

Ich wollte aber hier die Frage stellen ob eine solchen Satz eindeutig auf dem Auszug aus einer Wohnung hinweist oder ob es eventuell mit der Entfernung von Kleidung verwechselt werden könnte.

Comment: Ich habe folgende Korrekturen gemacht: 1. Das erste Wort eines Satz muss mit einem Großbuchstaben beginnen. 2. Der Infinitivsatz "in einem Monat auszuziehen" muss vom Hauptsatz durch ein Komma getrennt werden. 3. Jeder Satz wird mit einem Satzzeichen abgeschlossen. Hier liegt ein Aussagesatz vor, daher muss am Ende ein Punkt stehen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nein, das kann in diesem Satz nicht verwechselt werden, denn bezogen auf Kleidung ist es immer entweder "*etwas (Akkusativ)* ausziehen" oder "sich ausziehen".

> „Ich habe vor, **meinen Mantel** auszuziehen”
> „Ich habe vor, **mich** auszuziehen”

Ohne Akkusativ-Objekt und ohne Reflexivpronomen ist klar, dass es darum geht, aus einem Haus oder einer Wohnung auszuziehen.

Man kann diese zwei verschiedenen Bedeutungen von "ausziehen" trotzdem für Wortspiele und Mehrdeutigkeiten benutzen, und bei bestimmten  Formulierungen kann es zu Missverständnissen kommen.

Zum Beipiel gibt es einen Film aus dem Jahr 2006 mit dem deutschen Titel ["Zum Ausziehen verführt"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0427229/) (Originaltitel: "Failure to launch"). Aus dem Filmtitel wird nicht klar, welche Bedeutung von Ausziehen gemeint ist, dazu muss man erst den Plot des Films kennen.

Comment: In one sketch Michael "Bully" Herbig shouted "_Ausziehen! Ausziehen!_" as in cheering someone to strip naked. But then the camera shows people packing furniture into a transporter (to move).